# Difference between $_session[''] & $_session[""] in php

Tags: php

I searched but didn't find a question about this. Is there a difference between `$_session['var']` and `$_session["var"]` in PHP?

I know the difference of single and double quotes at the echo command but can't figure out the above. At my testing server it works fine both ways, but is there something deeper?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: store some info in session and do <?php echo $_SESSION['myvar]; echo $_SESSION["myvar"] ?> , there is your answer

Comment: See [info on the differences between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in the PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/language.types.string). Strings inside array references are still strings, and they follow exactly the same rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is as follows:-

```
Eg: $key = 'demo';
In single quote, 
$_SESSION['$key'] = $key; wont work.
But in double quotes,
$_SESSION["$key"] = $key; works.
```

Means you can pass `php` variable directly in double quotes but not in single quote.

Answer (score 3):

actually difference between " " and ' '.  Whenever  you write something inside ' ' it will consider as string. it cant recognize any variable or like this. but " " is working for  both  string and variable.

example:

```
$foo = 10;
echo '$foo';
output: $foo;
```

again for " ",

```
echo "$foo";
output: 10;
```

when you write $_session["$var"]. it will work.

but if you write    $_session['$var'] not going to work.

here $var is a variable. value can be $var = 'var' or like this.

Comment: what about for $_SESSION["success"] vs $_SESSION['success'] ?
where the parameter isnt a variable but just a value

Answer (score 0):

When you write something in  "", it gets parsed and written in '' never get parsed, echo's data as it is.

for example

$cur = 10;

echo "i need USD $cur.";

it will parse "" and will output as : i need USD 10.

but if you put it in ''

echo 'i need USD $cur.';

it will not parse it and output as : i need USD $cur.

Same thing applies for SESSION too. single quote works faster than double quote.

Answer (score 0):

`""` or `''` both aren't different in `$_SESSION[]`, unless you want to put variables on it, just like `$_SESSION["session_$sesscode"]`